# How do I split values in a list by parenthesis using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, list, split, parentheses

What I mean by split by value, assume a list has 1 string value:
    `mylist = ["3+4(5-3)-(9+4)"]`

I want to split the values so they are separate string values like: `mylist = ["3+4", "(", 5-3", ")", "-", "(", "9-4", ")"]`

So far, the below code I attached does the same thing, but splits it between operators so if I input `["3+3"]`, it will output

`mylist = ["3", "+", "3"]`

```
import re
mylist = input("Equation: ")
mylist = re.compile("(?<=\d)([- + / *])(?=\d)").split(mylist)
```

I'm just trying to make it so that it does the same thing with parenthesis because adding a parenthesis in the parameters mess with the regex syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile("([()])")
>>> r.split("abc(def(ghi)jkl")
['abc', '(', 'def', '(', 'ghi', ')', 'jkl']
>>>
```

The outer parentheses in the regex cause the separators to be retained as elements of the split list.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there anyway to combine the parenthesis splitting with the operator splitting like the code I provided above? re.compile the code twice and that gives me a list within a list. I'm trying to end up with a single list.

Comment: You can put any characters you want inside the square braces `[]`.  As long as the operators are single characters, that should work.  For example, you could use `"([()+-/*])"`.  If you want to split on spaces as well, you can add a single space (and they will appear in the split list).  Don't add multiple spaces as in the your post.  Each character is either present or absent, so repeating them doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. One more thing, you provided me with ~r.split(“text”)~ but when I go to plug in a variable there, the resulting list is has extra spaces at the beginning and end. For example, ~mylist = [“”,  “3”, “+”, “3”, “”]~

Comment: @Bottle Are you including digits as split characters?  The leading and trailing empty strings occur when the first (or last) character in the string is matched by the regex.  Using a variable vs. a fixed string makes no difference, it will behave the same for both if the string is the same.

Comment: Hi Tom. I noticed that the empty strings occur only when there are parenthesis present and only before or after a parenthesis. For example 3+3(3) = ['3', '+', '3', '(', '3', ')', '']. Also, can you explain what you mean by including digits as a split character? How would I go about doing so. Thanks.

Comment: @Bottle Hi.  What I mean is, the regular expression matches a set of substrings that are used to split the source string.  So the string is split into alternating substrings: [a1, b1, a2, b3, ..., an] where the "b" substrings match the regex, and the "a" substrings do not.  The outer parentheses cause the "b" substrings to be present in the output (otherwise you'd just have the "a" substrings).  So the question is which substrings are matched by the regex (i.e., the "b" substrings).  If two of them occur back-to-back, then the "a" substring that separates them will be empty.

Comment: @Bottle Similarly at the start and the end of the string, since the first and last substrings in the output are always "a" substrings, even if it needs to use empty strings for them (which happens if the regex matches the start (or end) of the string.